# Как вывести ключ/значение в prompt?

Tags: javascript, json, ecmascript-6

Есть JSON файл:

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    "question1": ["answ1", "answ2"],
  },
  {
    "question2": ["answ1", "answ2"],
  },
];
```

Как можно вывести поочередно вопрос в prompt из вариантами ответа в виде заполнения поля answer1/answer2?
Написал вывод вопросов поочередно, и теперь нужно чтобы заполнение поля было с вариантами ответа из JSON, как можно это сделать?

```js
tasks.forEach((item) => {
  const qKeys = Object.keys(item);
  qKeys.forEach((item) => {
    let question = prompt(item);
    alert(question);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Prompt невозможно редактировать кнопки ответа. Он принимает два аргумента: обязательный вопрос и необязательный текст по умолчанию.
[Подробнее](https://learn.javascript.ru/alert-prompt-confirm)

Если вы хотите выводить пары вопрос/ответ в текстовое поле со всеми вашими комбинациями вопросов и ответов, это так:

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    "question1": ["answ1", "answ2"],
  },
  {
    "question2": ["answ1", "answ2"],
  },
];

tasks.forEach((item) => {
  const qKeys = Object.keys(item);
    
  item[qKeys].forEach((item2) => {
    let question = prompt(qKeys, item2);
    alert(question);
  });
});
```

Либо по другому:

```js
const tasks = [
  {
    "question1": ["answ1", "answ2"],
  },
  {
    "question2": ["answ1", "answ2"],
  },
];

tasks.forEach((item) => {
  const qKeys = Object.keys(item);
    
  prompt(qKeys, `${item[qKeys][0]}/${item[qKeys][1]}`);
});
```

Смотря что вы хотите